# Get a reference to something I just inflated

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have an outer viewgroup (a ViewFlipper), and I want to programmatically put an inner view inside of it (a LinearLayout). I then want a reference to that inner view so I can do things with it later. So I'll have a line like this:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_linear_layout, myViewFlipper, true);
```

How can I get access to the inner view that I just inflated? The android docs for LayoutInflater claim that `.inflate` returns a reference to "the root View of the inflated hierarchy", but adds that "If root was supplied and attachToRoot is true, this is root", which I interpret to mean that in my case `.inflate` will return a reference to myViewFlipper.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout ) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_linear_layout, null, false);
myViewFlipper.addView(layout);
```

Comment: Doesn't the boolean flag in the call to .inflate() take care of .addView() ?

Comment: yeah but you are not specifying any root view, then later you add it to your view flipper

Answer (score 0):

You can also just search for that specific view?

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_linear_layout);
```

Or you can retrieve the first child of the ViewFlipper after inflating?

Anyway, `inflate` returns a View that you can use to search, find or do whatever you want with.